# How to cut time in datetime.date?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have 2 variables: `datetime.date` and `datetime.datetime`

```py
import sqlite3
from datetime import date


@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def start_message(message): 
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * from DATA WHERE id = ? ORDER BY DATE ", (message.from_user.id,))
        row = cursor.fetchone() #datetime.datetime
        datee = date.today() #datetime.date
        print(datee - parse(row[2]).date())
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, row[1])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(datee - parse(row[2])))
```

`print` is displaying `-1 day, 0:00:00`, but I need to take out the `timestamp`. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you provide more information? What is the issue? Do you get an error or do you want to add something to the code? What is your desired output, could you explicitly write it out?

Comment: i need to display -1 day, currently he displaying -1 day 0:00:00 @AntonvanderWel

Comment: if you want to return a date -1 day you can do: `new_date = datee - timedelta(1)` by importing `from datetime import datetime, timedelta
`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print the days (without the hours,minutes,seconds), you can use the attribute`.days`, e.g.:

```
print((datee - parse(row[2]).date()).days)
```

this works because what you receive is not a `date` object anymore but a `datetime.timedelta` object.